# military grade explosives -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example with a context (news article, [ISIS is manufacturing weapons at an alarming rate](http://www.businessinsider.com/isis-is-manufacturing-weapons-at-an-alarming-rate-2015-6)):

> IS is manufacturing the weapons at an alarming rate, using everything from fertilizer to **military grade explosives**.

I can understand the term *military explosives* perfectly well (materials used by the army people that explode when detonated), but what is *grade* supposed to mean?

Comment: They're not just using fertilizer to make "home-made" or crude explosives, which take barrels full to produce the explosion; they're using so-called "plastic explosives" like C-4, of which only a few pounds can produce immense explosions. The word should probably be hyphenated to make it clearer: military-grade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two definitions of the term "grade" from TFD are:

> 2. A position in a scale of size, quality, or intensity: a poor grade of lumber.
> 3. An accepted level or standard.

In this case, "military grade" means it's of the same quality generally demanded of military explosives. The term "military explosives" refers to explosives actually used by a military. If a military uses explosives that are very low-quality, they're still military explosives. In contrast, if a non-military organization makes high-quality explosives for mining, they're not military explosives.

Whether ISIS-made explosives are military or not depends only on if the speaker considers ISIS to be a military or not, not on their quality. However, in this case the reporter wanted to point out that ISIS was making high-quality explosives that are similar to the explosives of national armies. The term "grade" means that the speaker is talking about the *quality* of the explosives, instead of about who uses them.

(Similar terminology is used in the nuclear context: "weapons-grade uranium" refers to uranium that is pure enough to use in a nuclear bomb, even if it's not actually being used in a weapon. Again, "-grade" is about the quality of the uranium, as opposed to its actual use).

Comment: +1 In the same way, we speak of 'professional-grade' electronics and 'consumer-grade' (which these days tends to mean pro-grade five years ago).